# Copying data from staging table to multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, merge, staging-table

In SQL Server 2016 I have a staging table [S] with 8 columns. I want to copy that data to 3 tables [A], [B] and [C]. [A] has FK to [B] and [B] has FK to [C]. Columns 1-2 are to go to [c], column 3 to [a] and columns 4-8 to [B].

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? Efficiency is not paramount as only 5.5Krows.

Any help much appreciated.

edit:

Should have made it clearer:

- Tables a,b and c exist and have PK and FK's in place.
- c has a unique constraint on a concatination of col1 and col2.
- a,b, and c use the IDENTITY PK
- Data to be imported has been cleansed of duplicates.

Comment: 2 downvotes with no comment. Not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So effectively you're splitting up a row from S over 3 tables? 
Why not use primary key from table S instead of "chained" key you want to use?

You'd still be able to join the data the way you want, you would also be able to join tables A and C without using B.

p.s. If you don't have a PK in S, or is in a shape you don't want to copy, you can still use a surrogate key in one table and reference it from other two.

here's a solution for table C, you can adjust it for other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE c (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY
  , col1 int
  , col2 int
)
INSERT INTO c(id,col1,col2)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.PrimaryKey)
  , s.col1
  , s.col2
FROM s
```

or

```
INSERT INTO c(id,col1,col2)
SELECT
    s.PrimaryKey
  , s.col1
  , s.col2
FROM s
```

or (too implicit for my taste)

```
SELECT
    IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS ID
  , col1
  , col2
INTO c
FROM s
ORDER BY s.PrimaryKey
```

edit:
If you're trying to get rid of redundancies then you could use DENSE_RANK() like this (add/remove rank for keys you need):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS PK_a
  , s1.col1
INTO a
FROM s1

SELECT DISTINCT    
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col2,col3) AS PK_b
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS FK_a
  , s1.col2
  , s1.col3
INTO b
FROM s1

SELECT DISTINCT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col4) AS PK_c
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS FK_a
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col2, col3) AS FK_b
  , col4
INTO c
FROM s1
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Please see my edits.

Comment: You can always drop constraints and indexes while doing import from staging and recreate them after import is finished. Make use of natural keys to calculate surrogate ones. Use SET IDENTITY INSERT if you have identity columns, use DBCC RESEED to set the identity to proper value after is done. Just because data is cleansed of duplicates it doesn't mean there's no redundancies. If it doesn't have redundancies do you even need to split the table?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Entity Framework 6 BulkInsert tool. I found it easier to work with the model classes I already had defined. I just read all objects from staging into a list of staging objects before iterating over them and constructing a,b and c and finally saving them all in a single call. 5.5K rows in under 10secs.

Thanks for your assistance @Bistabil